# Draw virtual route of journey in Android using open GL or any other alternative

Tags: android

I have to draw virtual route of a person journey with different milestones. I want to know if it is entirely possible in android or I will have to use some alternative approach. If someone is suggesting alternative approach please elaborate. Also I don't need entire code but only suggestions and demo if anything similar is there.
The example of how the UI will look like is in the below referenced image.[image]